# A simple loop that loops when a option is not selected in Python

Tags: python, loops

I am having trouble with this loop, I have been teaching my self for two days now and I'm in a pinch. I have tried googling the answer but it's not helping me with this specific situation.

In Python, I am trying to prompt a user to pick three options and loop the question if one of the options is not selected.

My code is:

```py
power = input("pick a super power: strength, pyrokenisis, or speed---  ")

while power == "strength" or "pyrokenisis" or "speed":

    print("nice")
    break
else:

    print("try again")
```

Comment: You have to do while True and then add an if statement.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to test multiple variables against a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic is just slightly off. You are forgetting to re-prompt and your condition is wrong.

The condition:

```
power == "strength" or "pyrokenisis" or "speed"
```

checks if the power variable is equal to strength, or if either of the other two strings are "true". It may help to bracket it:

```
(power == "strength") or ("pyrokenisis") or ("speed")
```

Instead, you should be checking with:

```
power == "strength" or power == "pyrokenisis" or power == "speed"
```

or maybe use `in` on a tuple:

```
power in ("strength", "pyrokenisis", "speed")
```

So your final code could look something like:

```
while True:
    power = input("pick a super power: strength, pyrokenisis, or speed---  ")
    if power in ("strength", "pyrokenisis", "speed"):
        print("nice")
        break
    else:
        print("try again")
```

Notice that I have moved the prompt inside the `while` loop so that the user can actually try again on each loop. An `if` statement has also been used to control the program flow.

Answer (score 2):

Put it in a while loop, and add an if statement.

```java
while True:
  power = input("pick a super power: strength, pyrokenisis, or speed---  ")
  if power == "strength" or power == "pyrokenisis" or power == "speed":
    print("nice")
    break
  else:
    print("try again")
    continue
```